# How to display a child window on grid cell click using SelectedItem (mvvm approach)

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, selecteditem

I am a c# silverlight beginner and i have to use mvvm approach to achieve my task.
I have already created a GUI which look like this:

[image: http://prntscr.com/3c6ak5]

```
<UserControl x:Class="DEV_CENTER.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DEV_CENTER"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ProgramViewModel x:Key="ProgramViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Progr}" IsReadOnly="True"  DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
        </data:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now i have to create a child window by clicking on "`sso`" and another child window for "`program2`" click which are just below the heading(`SerialNumber`).This child window will contain some button and text box as well.

Where should i make change to do so.I have to use Mvvm approach to do so. 
Is using "selection list" a right approach, **If i use "selection list" then how to bind it and how to link it with Model.cs and ViewModel.cs ? Could some one please help me to give  piece of codes for ViewModel.cs and Model.cs  and View.xaml?**
Would be a big help. Thanks

NOTE: Please note that i don't have to Gala and any third library (i prefer binding using SelectedItem)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to achieve what you are trying to do by using DataGridTemplateColumn as shown here http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-DataGrid-Column-types.aspx

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Serial Number">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="btnSerialNumber" Text="{Binding SerialNumber}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="btnSerialNumber_Click" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

or by using style, targeting only the DataGridCell as shown in http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing

add the style to your control resource

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DataGridCellClickStyle">  
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
</Style>
```

and then add the CellStyle and reference the above created DataGridCellClickStyle

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" Width="2*" CellStyle={StaticResource DataGridCellClickStyle}"/>'
```

Make sure to use DataGridTemplateColumn or apply the style to the SerialNumber column only.
Then inside the btnSerialNumber_Click or DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler you can get the exact cell and object that it is bound to it, and then you can  launch the second window

Comment: but you have button in your code. I just have to click on grid cell and there should be CHILDWINDOW POP6UP ON IT. No buttons

Comment: I've also updated the DataGridTemplateColumn using TextBlock and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event instead of Button and Click event